# How can I filter out duplicate and empty documents as well as order a MongoDB Collection with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, meteor, duplicates, mongodb-query, meteor-helper

Getting all the data in a MongoDB collection is as easy as it gets. You just use the Collection instance name and call find:

```
TimeAndSpace = new Mongo.Collection('timeAndSpace');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    . . .
    Template.placesLived.helpers({
        places: function () {
            // this helper returns a cursor of all of the documents in the collection
            return TimeAndSpace.find();
        }
    });
}
```

But my Collection has some duplicate data and some empty records. How do I filter these out? Also I want to order by two fields. My Collection is structured and written to thus:

```
TimeAndSpace = new Mongo.Collection('timeAndSpace');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.addTimeSpaceForm.events({
        'submit form': function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var city = event.target.city.value;
            var state = event.target.state.value;
            var yearin = event.target.yearin.value;
            var yearout = event.target.yearout.value;

            Meteor.call('insertLocationData', city, state, yearin, yearout);
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  Meteor.methods({
      'insertLocationData': function(city, state, yearin, yearout){
          TimeAndSpace.insert({
              ts_city: city,
              ts_state: state,
              ts_yearin: yearin,
              ts_yearout: yearout
          });
      }
  });
}
```

I want the documents to be ordered first by yearin, then by yearout (so that if there are multiple documents with the same yearin value (such as 1984), they would be returned in this order:

```
Helena      Montana     1984    1984
San Andreas California  1984    1987
```

(not vice versa)

So how do I filter out empty and redundant documents, and order documents by specified fields?

### UPDATE

Thinking that maybe the problem with the answer not returning any data was that the "city" field should be "ts_city" and the "state" field should be "ts_state", I tried this:

```
return TimeAndSpace.find(
  {ts_city: {$exists: true, ne: ""}, ts_state: {$exists: true, ne: ""}},
  {sort: {ts_yearin: 1, ts_yearout: 1}}
);
```

...but it still returns no data.

### UPDATE 2

When I enter this in the console:

```
TimeAndSpace.find(
  {ts_city: {$exists: true, ne: ""}, ts_state: {$exists: true, ne: ""}},
  {sort: {ts_yearin: 1, ts_yearout: 1}}
);
```

I get:

```
Exception in template helper: Error: Inconsistent operator: {"$exists":true,"ne":""}
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1269:15
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at isOperatorObject (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1263:5)
    at compileValueSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1459:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1439:9
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at compileDocumentSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1422:5)
    at _.extend._compileSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1399:12)
    at new Minimongo.Matcher (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1342:27)
    at new LocalCollection.Cursor (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:144:20)
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=8zcc5akr4u".
return TimeAndSpace.find(
  {sort: {ts_yearin: 1, ts_yearout: 1}}
);
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
TimeAndSpace.find(
  {ts_city: {$exists: true, ne: ""}, ts_state: {$exists: true, ne: ""}},
  {sort: {ts_yearin: 1, ts_yearout: 1}}
);
Uncaught Error: Inconsistent operator: {"$exists":true,"ne":""}
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1269:15
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at isOperatorObject (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1263:5)
    at compileValueSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1459:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1439:9
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at compileDocumentSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1422:5)
    at _.extend._compileSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1399:12)
    at new Minimongo.Matcher (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:1342:27)
    at new LocalCollection.Cursor (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo.js?af9eb9d7447544ca9b839a3dcf7ed2da2209b56c:144:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the easy ones first, eliminating blanks and sorting:

```
return TimeAndSpace.find(
  {ts_city: {$exists: true, $ne: ""}, ts_state: {$exists: true, $ne: ""}},
  {sort: {ts_yearin: 1, ts_yearout: 1}}
);
```

Deduplication on the other hand is probably best handled by a cron job that looks for the kinds of dupes you're concerned with and deletes the offending documents. It's not really possible during a query and it would be a PIA during rendering.

Comment: I added a second "}" to the sort line to get it to "compile" (and added that above, too), but now it returns nothing...

Comment: sorry, forgot your `ts_` prefixes on the city and state keys

Comment: I added the err msgs I get in the console to Update 2.

Comment: Yep, prepending the "$" to the "ne"s does the trick - thanks!